# How do I prove Bayes Theorem via induction?

Tags: probability, proof-writing, bayes-theorem

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXvXV.png)

Hey everyone,

In the linked exercise I was asked to prove Bayes Theorem for a finite sequence by taking the case i=1 and prove via induction.

As a first step I already proved the case i=1, which I did in the "classical way":

$$P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A) = P(B|A)P(A) = P(A|B)P(B)$$
which leads to $$P(A | B) = \frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}P(A)$$

My intuition is as follows: We can think of   $$P(A | B) = \frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}P(A)$$ as P(A) multiplied by a factor which makes A more or less likely depending on the relative probability of B|A with regards to B.

For multiple signals this intuition naturally extends to the above given formula. What I have problems with is a formal way of how to prove the question given induction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: To simplify the notation asume that $B_1$ is $A$ (for me seems more clear that way). Then use the case you proved to get $P[\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n B_i]=P[B_n\vert \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} B_i] \cdot P[\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} B_i] $ now you can apply the induction step to the last term.